# MicrosoftResourceHealth azure.core.exceptions.DeserializationError exception

Tags: python, azure, azure-sdk-python

Problem is that sample code raises exception.

```
import json

from azure.identity import AzureCliCredential,DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.mgmt.resourcehealth import MicrosoftResourceHealth

#https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/main/sdk/resourcehealth/azure-mgmt-resourcehealth

def main():

    resourcehealth_client = MicrosoftResourceHealth(
        credential=AzureCliCredential(),
        subscription_id = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'
    )
        

    emerging_events_list = list(resourcehealth_client.emerging_issues.list())
    print(f"There are {len(emerging_events_list)} emerging issues items")
      

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Exception;

```
azure.core.exceptions.DeserializationError: (', ValueError: Invalid datetime string: 2023-02-23 11:23:39Z', 'Cannot deserialize datetime object.', ValueError('Invalid datetime string: 2023-02-23 11:23:39Z'))
```

Whereas other operations are successful, e.g.

```
availability_statuses_list = list(resourcehealth_client.availability_statuses.list_by_subscription_id())
```

How is it possible to return data from emerging issues?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**
Initially, I got an same error in my environment.

> azure.core.exceptions.DeserializationError: (', DeserializationError: (", DeserializationError: (', ValueError: Invalid datetime string:2023-02-25 06:15:04Z', 'Cannot deserialize datetime object.', ValueError('Invalid datetime string: 2023-02-25 06:15:04Z'))",'Unable to deserialize response data. Data: 2023-02-25 06:15:04Z, iso-8601'

The above error indicates that the Azure SDK for Python is unable to deserialize a response from the Microsoft Resource-health API due to an invalid datetime string.

The datetime string '**`2023-02-25 06:45:45Z`**' in the response appears to be in an invalid format, which is causing the deserialization error. Actually python format should be **`2023-02-25 06:45:45`** AFAIK, this is due to Azure python SDK issue.

As a workaround, you can use this [Ms-Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resourcehealth/2018-07-01/emerging-issues/list?tabs=HTTP) to list the emergency issues with REST API using graph explorer:

**Command:**

```
GET https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.ResourceHealth/emergingIssues?api-version=2018-07-01
```

**Response:**

```
 {
  "value": [
    {
      "id": "/providers/Microsoft.ResourceHealth/emergingissues/default",
      "type": "/providers/Microsoft.ResourceHealth/emergingissues",
      "name": "default",
      "properties": {
        "refreshTimestamp": "2023-02-25 07:14:19Z",
        "statusBanners": [],
        "statusActiveEvents": []
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Postman:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks. As another workaround, emerging_issues are available also from ResourceHealth events.